# Unable to clear text area in Swagger UI; always defaulting to empty braces

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have a method as below to accept a POST request:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String test(@Parameter("The body of a request") @RequestBody String body) {
}
```

In the Swagger UI, the default value shown on the text box is "string". If I try to clear the text box, it would then default to "{}". I would like the user to be able to paste his own JSON text into the text box, but how is he able to clear the existing "{}" in the text box first?

Is it possible to set a default JSON text, but still allow the user to clear it and paste his own?

What I am using:
springfox-boot-starter version 3.0.0